# Setting up a FTP cron job on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, ftp

Is there a way to have an FTP client or setup a task where the system will connect to an FTP server and download all files at a certain time in the night? I'm on Windows and was unsure if there is a way to this with the OS cmd line or if an FTP client could do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are two parts: Windows Task Scheduler and Powershell.
First create a small powershell script to connect and transfer your file. For security, Powershell is disabled from running scripts, so you'll need to first enable to run locally created scripts.
[Here's one example of powershell ftp script.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867385/upload-files-with-ftp-using-powershell)
Once you have it running the way you like, use the task scheduler (from the control panel) to run the script nightly.